# How to register multiple types by name using Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am new to Unity (from Castle Windsor land) so I know what I want to do with dependancy injection I am just unsure of how to do it with Unity.

Guidance would be appreciated.

And further some implementations like this:

```
public class Strategy
{
... etc
}

public class FooStrategy : Strategy
{
... etc    
}

public class BarStrategy : Strategy
{
... etc    
}
```

Currently I can register these one by one like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IStrategy, FooStrategy>("FooStrategy");
container.RegisterType<IStrategy, BarStrategy>("BarStrategy");

var foo = container.Resolve<IStrategy>("FooStrategy");
Assert.IsTrue(foo.GetType() == typeof (FooStrategy));
```

How can I do this more efficiently? I want to register all types implementing IStrategy by their implementation name.

Comment: You want something like automatically grab all implementations and register them in container?

Comment: Yup so instead of registering my types one by one as above, I want to say `register all types that implement IStrategy, with the name of the concrete type` the outcome would be the same as above.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(t => typeof(Strategy).IsAssignableFrom(t)));
```

It seems that by default the `Name` used in the container is the implementation name, so it is quite trivial in the end.

The only thing I had to change was to use a POCO as a base type, instead of an interface.